# In Visual Studio 2012, how can one link resource file(.rc) with c ++ dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have to build a c++ .dll, where I need to show a dialog box in some
cases to interact with users. So I create a resource file (.rc),
integrate corresponding code in the dll project to show the dialog and
build the dll project with the resource file in VS2012.

Now the problem is when I load the dll in another test application and
call one of the method from dll which uses the resource file to show
dialogBox, this method returns

> Error 0x715 is ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND.**

The line inside the dll that returns the error is

```
DialogBox(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_INPUTDIALOG), NULL, NotifyUser);
```

It seems that my resource file (.rc) for DialogBox with **id:
IDD_INPUTDIALOG** is not linked or added in the dll. so it can not
find the dialog box resource.

Now if i *add a resource file(.rc) in the test application* with the same id as the resource file(.rc) in dll, the method call from dll uses the resource file(.rc) in test application , not the one in dll.

So is it the case that resource file is not liked or added in the dll?

Additional Info:

To build the dll with resource file, I use VS2012 and simply add the resource file in the project and build the project as dynamic link library (.dll).

Is it enough to add the resource file in dll, or do I have to set some
other flags or linker option to link the resource file (.rc) with dll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you pass the `HInstance` of the DLL? The `DialogBox` function needs to know where to search.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters. I have passed the HInstance  as NULL. Now i edit my code and get the hInstance using this [link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/tips/article.php/c3635/Tip-Detecting-a-HMODULEHINSTANCE-Handle-Within-the-Module-Youre-Running-In.htm).It works now.

Comment: Well, `HInstance==NULL` means "get the resource from the EXE" so it's no surprise that Windows can't find the resource in the DLL when you tell Windows to look elsewhere.

Comment: @MSalters you should write this as an answer - it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the comment which confirms `HInstance==NULL`, it means the call is really `DialogBox(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_INPUTDIALOG), NULL, NotifyUser);`. This looks for a dialog box in the EXE file of the process. That is the default location. To tell Windows to look elsewhere, you need the correct DLL instance.

To figure out your own instance from inside your DLL, call `GetModuleHandle`.